# Finding integer solution of congruence equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find all integer solution $x$ which are solutions to the following congruence relation:

> $243x+17=101$  (mod 725)

In this question, I can only figure out 243 and 725 are relatively prime. But I have no any idea on it.

Answer (score 1):

$243x=725y+84\iff81\cdot3~x=81~(9y+1)-(4y-3)\iff4y-3=81(9y-3x+1)$, at which point it's hard not to notice that $81+3=84=4\cdot21$. Can you take it from here ? :-$)$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**   $x=243^{-1} \cdot (101-17) \mod 725$.